# Where can I get Bootstrap transitions.js from?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to use the [Bootstrap Collapse plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).

> Collapse requires the transitions plugin to be included in your
>   version of Bootstrap.

I've downloaded `bootstrap-3.3.7-dist.zip` but it does not contain `transitions.js` mentioned here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#transitions

I've looked at the Gitbub rep (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev/js/dist), with no luck.

Where can I get Bootstrap `transitions.js` from please?

Answer (score 4):

The dist/js folder includes the bootstrap compiled js, and the documentation says this :

> If you're using the compiled (or minified) bootstrap.js, there is no need to include this—it's already there.

Otherwise, you can [You can download the sources](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.3.7.zip) and the file is in the js folder.

Answer (score 0):

I always add this code to my HTML file and everything works fine for me. Here is the link for Bootstrap collapse [Bootstrap Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: "About transitions
For simple transition effects, include transition.js once alongside the other JS files. If you're using the compiled (or minified) bootstrap.js, **there is no need to include this—it's already there.**"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code from Github,

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/js/transition.js

Answer (score 0):

CSS is also required for individual code of collapse functionality

```
<script src="js/Plugins/bootstrap-collapse/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>

<style>
.collapse {display: none;}
.collapse.in {display: block;}
.collapsing {position: relative;height: 0;overflow: hidden;-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;-o-transition-timing-function: ease;transition-timing-function: ease;-webkit-transition-duration: .35s;-o-transition-duration: .35s;transition-duration: .35s;-webkit-transition-property: height,visibility;-o-transition-property: height,visibility;transition-property: height,visibility;}
</style>
```

I have created a .js file which is combination of both [transition.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/js/transition.js) & [collapse.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/js/src/collapse.js)

Answer (score 0):

it is by default compiled inside the main bootstrap.js(and its min counterpart) file. you can easily open it(non-minified version) and see something like the following comments

```
 /* ========================================================================
     * Bootstrap: transition.js v3.4.1
     * https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#transitions
     * ========================================================================
     * Copyright 2011-2019 Twitter, Inc.
     * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
     * ======================================================================== */
......

    /* ========================================================================
     * Bootstrap: collapse.js v3.4.1
     * https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#collapse
     * ========================================================================
```

also note that in main [custom download page of bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/#plugins) all plugins are selected unless you want smaller and customized js and css files